# iframe video ask for download in safari

Tags: html, video, iframe, browser, safari

I need to play local video in browser itself using `<iframe>` But it is asking for download in **safari** browser. It works fine with all other browsers like Chrome, Mozilla, etc.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Video</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
   <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="D:/Video/Video1.mp4" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen seamless></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Works fine for me in safari on mac. The only difference I can think of is the forward slash in the window path. Windows uses backslashes for path so can you try to change the path in src attribute of iframe to src="D:\Video\Video1.mp4"?

Comment: But it is not working in my safari browser on windows 10.

Comment: Yes that is why I am thinking it has something to do with the path. Did you try changing the forward slashes to backward slashes?

Comment: Yes, I tried with backward slashes also but it is not working for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the driver letter from the path, it should be: "/Video/Video1.mp4" or "./Video/Video1.mp4" assuming the page is in the same folder level as the "Video" folder. Give it a try, let us know.